# ffmpeg: same compilations behaving differently across different machines

Tags: ffmpeg, x86-64

I am using ffmpeg on two of my Ubuntu hardy boxes. Both of them have same version of pre-compiled binaries of FFMPEG from Medibuntu. When I convert 3GP to FLV, on one machine ffmpeg distorts sound while on the other it works fine.

I have checked the version and formats options and they are all identical across the machines.

The only difference is that one machine is 64-bit while the other is 32-bit. Could this be the cause of the problem? If that is the case how do I get it resolved?

Comment: $ffmpeg -version
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-pp --enable-swscaler --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libogg --enable-libgsm --enable-dc1394 --disable-debug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaac --enable-xvid --enable-x264 --enable-liba52 --enable-amr_nb --enable-amr_wb --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
  libavutil version: 1d.49.3.0
  libavcodec version: 1d.51.38.0
  libavformat version: 1d.51.10.0
  built on Mar 17 2009 21:37:49
ffmpeg      SVN-rUNKNOWN
libavutil   3212032
libavcodec  3352064
libavformat 3344896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 32- vs. 64-bit could be the problem. To solve, first I'd try grabbing the most recent ffmpeg sources from http://ffmpeg.org and compiling them yourself.

Second, assuming its the 32-bit version that works, I'd just use the 32-bit version on the 64-bit host. You may need to install some 32-bit library to make this work, or compile it statically.

Also, you could try a different audio codec, or different parameters.